# Do we need to restart TFS Services periodically

Tags: tfs

We have TFS 2013 & TFS 2017 environments. For increased stability is it advisable to restart the Windows TFS Services (i.e. Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent, Team Foundation SSH Service) on periodic basis i.e. every weekend (to recycle the processes and memory threads)

My understanding is that this is not needed, however wanted to confirm it.

Comment: No, you don't need to manually restart anything unless there's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not needed to restart TFS Services periodically. But if there is some change, or problem, you could try to restart the service. For example.

- After you install new software on a build agent machine, you must
  restart the build agent service for the new capability to show up in
  the pool so that the build can run.
- If you change the password of the account that running the service, you need to update the logon information of the service and restart it.

Comment: Thank you Cece, appreciate your quick response.